# How to align two divs inline?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs 1)with the icon 2)with the text related to it.
I want to align them in a line.

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
                <h4>Stunning Layouts</h4>
                    <div class="one"><i class="fa fa-heart service_icon"></i></div>
                    <div class="one"><a class="service_para">A website that works perfectly good and give a user warm experience on all mobile and tablet browsers.A website that works perfectly good and give a user warm experience on all mobile and tablet browsers. </a></div>
            </div>
```

and my css is like

```
.service{
    background-color:#fff;
    padding:30px 100px;
}

.service_icon{
    color:#fff;
    background-color:#CE1E47;
    padding:20px;
    margin-right:10px;
    border-radius:50%;
}

.one{
    display:inline;
    height:100%;
}
```

but if i write more text it gets written under the icon. i want both of them separated side by side even if i write 100 lines of text.

i hope you get it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: table-cell` is what you need.

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7h6Lmf4e/)

update your css -

```
.one{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: there is still a big space over the second div..check your fiddle plz..how do i remove that?

Comment: @SohilShah just add - `vertical-align: top;` to the `.one` - http://jsfiddle.net/7h6Lmf4e/1/

Comment: @SohilShah Is that fixes all the problems?? then consider marking the answer as best answer (whichever you find best) :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods, here's one using positioning and padding:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RWGQyG

```
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <h4>Stunning Layouts</h4>
  <div class="icon-text">
    <i class="fa fa-heart service_icon"></i>
    <p>A website that works perfectly good and give a user warm experience on all mobile and tablet browsers.A website that works perfectly good and give a user warm experience on all mobile and tablet browsers. A website that works perfectly good and give a user warm experience on all mobile and tablet browsers.A website that works perfectly good and give a user warm experience on all mobile and tablet browsers</p>
  </div>  
</div>

.icon-text{
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.service_icon{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   color:#fff;
   background-color:#CE1E47;
   padding:20px;
   margin-right:10px;
   border-radius:50%;
}
```

Comment: yes...thats right...but it's tricky...isn't there a simple way to do so?

Comment: Why is it tricky? Only 4 properties are required. Here's an example of another way to do it using `:before` (arguably 'trickier'): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24685355/aligning-li-text-that-wraps-when-using-custom-bullet-point

Comment: I think it was easier to solve with " display:table-cell". since it also allowed to use vertical align property,i don't need to go with position property.

Answer (score 0):

Add this css.

```
.service_icon{
 color:#fff;
 background-color:#CE1E47;
 padding:20px;
 margin-right:10px;
 border-radius:50%;
 display: inline-block;
}

.one{
  display:inline;
  height:100%;
  float: left;
}

.one:first-child{
 width: 20%;
}
.one:last-child{width: 80%;}
```

you can test here http://jsfiddle.net/prakashlaxkar/z6m9zk8m/